# control a server before the OS loads

Tags: dell-poweredge, server-setup, amt

I have a [Dell Poweredge R430](http://www.dell.com/learn/us/en/45/shared-content~data-sheets~en/documents~dell-poweredge-r430-spec-sheet.pdf) server running Ubuntu server 16.04.1,

On the Ubuntu I have KVM running some virtual machines,

I need to have the maximal control over the server by a remote connection, that if the Ubuntu fails to load for some reason I can have another access, for example some loader that runs before the OS loads,

I read about Intel [AMT KVM](https://software.intel.com/sites/manageability/AMT_Implementation_and_Reference_Guide/default.htm?turl=WordDocuments%2Fkvmandintelamt.htm), is this the best practice at our days? are there any existing tools to use it to reformat the machine to some 'ready drive' or to handle problems at the machine?

Comment: As @Sven said. use iDRAC. The documentation you posted clearly states it as an option.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your server should have [DRAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dell_DRAC) available and there are most likely upgrade licenses available to allow full remote management capabilities (including remote video that works completely without OS). DRAC is an [IPMI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_Platform_Management_Interface)
 implementation.

This is also available on most other server lines under various names.

AMT is a desktop management technology.